# redirect happening without .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have recently migrated a site ausmotorsearch.com.au to WP onto my cpanel VPS with around 20 other sites.

The new site insists on redirecting to non www despite there being no  .htaccess request to do so...in fact when I try to use .htacess to force www - I get a too many redirect errors.  I have other sites on same server using identical code with no error.  I can't figure out where the original non www redirect is happening - DNS is also identical for other sites

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the WP itself configured for the www URL? eg, `WP_SITEURL` constant or related config option? Otherwise, WP will redirect you. (Presumably you have more directives in your `.htaccess` file?)

Comment: MrWhite - I have checked all the obvious places for a WP redirect and come up blank - and yes there is all the usual code in the .htaccess file.  I

Comment: What HTTP status code are you seeing? What kind of site was this before migrating to WP? Bit of an aside, but you seem to have put the non-www to www redirect in the wrong place as it looks like you’ve chopped off a RewriteRule directive?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 22:18:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie,User-Agent
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6ad9e372b972e4f7701197b122dcf527; path=/
Location: https://ausmotorsearch.com.au/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I have searched httpd.conf and can find no redirect

Comment: I tried another theme and initially no change however using the other theme I changed to Site URL in WP General settings and it worked - I could access www but as soon as I returned to custom theme it reverted to non www ....so I am on the track